# Is it technologically possible for IVR systems to recognize and support pulse dialing

Tags: pulse, telephone, rotary

I understand all the concepts behind IVR systems.

I've *never* been able to quite understand *why* pulse dialing can't be used with IVR systems. Tones are obviously sent to the other party, but a pulse is essentially a quick disconnect and connect of the circuit, so wouldn't the other party be able to somehow sense that disruption? Today, most phone companies don't use Strowger switches - they use digital switches meaning they are already using computers to "read" the pulses being sent down the line, so I don't understand why they couldn't just 'pass' those pulses on to the called party. The only answers I've seen online is "it costs too much" which is just ridiculous because pulse dialing can be done with purely mechanical equipment and there is no reason a computer cannot listen for pulses the same way it listens for tones.

Am I missing something else here? I am assuming that pulses are detectable by the called party and that the equipment reading pulses is digital (basically a computer of some sort). I'm not sure why pulses can't be passed on from the central office in the same manner as DTMF tones, especially since my understanding is that the other part can hear audible clicks on the line if you spin the dial or rapidly depress the switchhook when on a call.

In fact, I have just confirmed this. I can hear VERY LOUD pulses through the receiver when the calling telephone's dial is released, just as one would expect.

Note: I am not referring to the use of the * and # keys, which you obviously can't emulate when pulse dialing; but rather how any digit cannot be pulse dialed and used with IVR systems.

IVR = Interactive Voice Response (i.e. Press 1 for X, Press 2 for Y, Press 3 for Z, etc...)

I have two Panasonic PBX systems at home and they both automatically convert pulses to tones when an outgoing call is made. So the telephone company could easily do the SAME thing with absolutely NO additional cost. My PBXs make it seem like pulses and tones are equally easy to forward to the caller (I've tested and tones and pulses can both be heard by the caller) so systems should be smart enough to recognize simple pulses in addition to tones.

Obviously, * and # could not be simulated using pulses but you can't have everything...

From previous comments, I've gotten the vibe that companies just choose not to support it. But given the telephone company can recognize pulses using the same equipment, I am not sure why the same cannot be said for customer premises equipment that listens to keypad input. Regardless of whether or not it is or should be supported, is this feasible and possible??

Comment: In band signaling is easier to listen to. DTMF decoders can work with more noise without risking disconnect. Simpler hardware. Various guesses here. Someone should provide a verifiable answer soon.

Comment: If you MUST use acronyms.. please expand it once in your question. Not everyone knows what IVR means but may know why you can or can't do what you are asking.

Comment: One reason is probably to do with the way the "second line" functions work. That is, to switch lines you make a quick disconnect. Would be the same as dialing a 1 with a rotary I believe. If that was surmountable, I doubt they would pass it on as pulses though, more likely they would translate it back into tones at the exchange.

Comment: Considering that pulse dialing is basically only a historical oddment at this point, I'd assume that most of the things that "could" support it just haven't bothered, because who the heck still uses rotary phones anymore?

Comment: If pointing out that rotary phones are only a historical oddment to you is a "blighted opinion", I'd guess you don't get out much? The point isn't that it's not *possible*, it's that the enormous market share that is probably just you isn't sufficient to fund the people who make interactive voice systems to add support.

Comment: On the other hand, since your profile seems to indicate you believe RF is a carcinogen (!), I think I'm fairly safe in assuming you're not generally convinced by facts, evidence or that pesky reality thing, so I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Uh, no.  RF is NOT a carcinogen.  Check your facts, and get them from some where besides the whacko nutjob sites.  You'll not make many friends here by spouting that nonsense to people who work with RF everyday and know that RF is a safe as anything else on this planet.  BTW:  I hope you stay indoors a lot.  The sun is one huge honking source of RF.

Comment: @JRE RF is a Class 2B carcinogen. I'm simply relaying what the World Health Organization said in 2011. If you don't think it's a carcinogen, take it up with them, not me. I'm just the messenger, so shooting me does no good

Comment: No reliable studies have proven a connection.  Given the sheer numbers of cellphone/smartphone users out there today, it'd be damned obvious if they were causing as much cancer as you claim.  Have fun saving your half an RJ11 cable.

Comment: Really.  Post a link to that WHO site.

Comment: @JRE You sound like an electrical engineer, not a health expert. If you know anything about cancer, you'd know that cancer takes decades to develop. People have not been using cell phones long enough, and many of the effects are starting to show. IARC has also classified it: http://emfsafetynetwork.org/wireless-devices-potential-cancer-risk-says-world-health-organization/

Comment: @Trevor. I just tried using two of my rotaries. Dialing 1 is not the same as flashing the switchhook.

Comment: Cellphones have been in use for decades.  At least 20 years, and two way radios for decades before that.  There have been studies on going for all that time.  Besides, how many people have you seen who have had a cancer that could be traced back to phone or radio use?

Comment: So where's the WHO link?

Comment: @JRE 12 mins ago

Comment: I like where it says "the evidence doesn't support it but we're going to call it a carcinogen anyway."

Comment: @JRE It does not say that on that page. You clearly haven't learned from history. Smoking, tobacco, asbestos, foot x-rays, etc. were all situations where the government told us these things were safe, the industry covered up the evidence, activists and whistleblowers were ridiculed, and there had to be a serious body count before policy was changed. Wait 30 years and we'll see who's laughing at who

Comment: Actually, it does.  You need to read it again.  It also was common knowledge for decades that smoking was bad for you.

Comment: @JRE And soon it will be common knowledge that wireless is bad for you